# Check if the website is up

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ecmascript-6, status-monitoring

**api.js**

```
'use strict';
const http = require('http');

module.exports = url => {
  const options = {
    host: url,
    method: 'HEAD',
    path: '/'
  };
  const req = http.request(options);
  req.end();
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let connected = false;
    req.on('response', res => {
      connected = res.statusCode < 500;
      resolve(connected);
    });

    req.on('error', err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
  return promise;
};
```

The most confusing part for me is which status codes should be considered a valid candidate? apart from that any comments regarding code are welcome.

Comment: My proxy answers 403 for non existing sites such as http://shbrtze.com/

Comment: It seems that my code is throwing error for unavailable sites too instead this should be transparent to the client and should get false instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the server does not exists it seems node throws an `EIO` error.

Now you need to make a decision, you can either reject the promise or resolve with false. From an usage point of view I would say I would prefer to resolve it false **unless I need to know why the server is unavailable**.

I am assuming that you just want to know if it is available or not, thus it doesn't make sense to reject the promise ever.

Your module also doesn't support [Urls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), in the form of

> scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path[?query][#fragment]

In order to support that you must parse the parameter with the existing `URL` module.

In order to support both the URL and the URN you can check if the protocol was specified

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require("url");
var Promise = require('promise');

module.exports = function (uri) {
  var address = url.parse(uri); 
  var parts = uri.split('/');
  var options = {
    host: address.protocol != null ? address.host : parts[0],
    method: 'HEAD',
    path: address.protocol != null ? address.pathname : parts.slice(1).join('/')
  };
  var req = http.request(options);
  req.end();
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var connected = false;
    req.on('response', function (res) {
      connected = res.statusCode < 500;
      resolve(connected);
    });

    req.on('error', function (err) {
      resolve(false);
    });
  });
  return promise;
};

module.exports("http://httpstat.us/200").then(function(isAvailable){
    console.log(isAvailable);
});
```

Comment: LGTM, but I want that the user can type `httpstat.us` and still get the result, while using `url` module its not possible(I tried that), wdyt?

Comment: @CodeYogi FML that is what I think, I wish that `url`would support that, but I guess they didn't support because the scheme/protocol is not specified. Look at the edited answer

Comment: What if no `url` is provided? and is `500` status check is enough?

Comment: @CodeYogi Seems that the promise is rejected as expected (with empty string) and even with my proxy it seems there still was a request to a DNS check that resulted in the EIO error. So it seems status `codes < 500` are enough.

Comment: IMHO I think its better to raise error if url is not present rather than let it fail silently, here is the [repo ](https://github.com/vivekimsit/is-site-up) which is online now, feel free to make any changes there.